# React-Native: Dismiss/Exit React-Native View back to Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I have an existing app that I am working on integrating React-Native for a portion of it. I am
having trouble understanding how to 'exit' react-native and get back to a native view.

Here's some code:

```
// Main objective-c code that bootstraps the react-native view. This view is loaded as a modal view.
MainViewController.m:

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleName:@"IndexApp" initialProperties:props launchOptions:nil];

    rootView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-49);
    [self.view addSubview:rootView];

}
```

My initial react views are such:

```
render() {
  return (
      <Navigator
          style={styles.container}
...
```

I have a right-nav button on the Navigator that I would like to "dismiss" the react view and the underlying MainViewController native view.

I have tried a callback to MainViewController from the react view like so, but without avail:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(dismiss:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
    NSLog(@"dismiss...");
    // these don't do anything
    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // anything with _rootView doesn't do anything, i.e. _rootView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Any help with an approach to 'exit' the react-native view and get back into native views would be appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried a callback to MainViewController", how did you do this?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've found this works is [this](https://github.com/tejasd/ios-playground/commit/ba0a695563377771c6ca9121bb2136122ccc5a64)

The gist of it is:

1. Create a NotificationManager class in Obj-C and expose it as React Module
2. In the ViewController register for a notification which when receives triggers [self dismissViewController..]

Comment: Works Perfectly! I was wondering as its been 4 years are there some newer easier/cooler ways to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the pop or dismiss on the main thread:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(dismiss:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
    NSLog(@"dismiss...");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        // use pop instead if this view controller was pushed onto a navigation controller
        //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please guide me through the steps as to how you exposed your class and this method to react native module?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: THIS DOESN"T WORK - I've left this here as an example of what doesn't work. Check my other answer for an approach that works.

If you present MainViewController this way, `popViewController:` should work

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
RCTRootView *reactView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                    moduleName:@"SimpleApp"
                                             initialProperties:nil
                                                 launchOptions:nil];


MainViewController *rootViewController = [MainViewController new];
rootViewController.view = reactView;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
```